# Reverse Geocode From Marker Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/allmyfindstest.html) page, which allows the user to view map markers.

I have a problem though with the reverse geocoding functionality that I'd like to include on the page.

When the user clicks on the map marker I would like to be able to populate the two text fields with the lat and lng co-ordinates (already saved within a mySQL database), automatically performing a reverse goeocode and adding the address to the 'address' text field.

I can populate the lat and lng text fields but I can't get the reverse geocode to work. I've checked the Javascript in JS Fiddle and there doesn't seem to be a problem there, and I've also been looking at the articles by Gabriel Svennerberg but I can't find out where I'm going wrong.

Could someone perhaps take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event doesn't seem to call your reversegeocode() function. You might want to change it to something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            document.getElementById('dateoftrip').value = this.formdateoftrip;
            document.getElementById('findcategory').value = this.formfindcategory; 
            document.getElementById('finddescription').value = this.formfinddescription;
            document.getElementById('findosgb36lat').value = this.formfindosgb36lat;
            document.getElementById('findosgb36lon').value = this.formfindosgb36lon;
            reversegeocode();
            });
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to  reply to my post and the solution. Kind regards